A topology on $\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N\}$ such that $S_\infty:=\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \text{ bijection}\}$ is a $G_\delta$ set

Construct a topology on $\mathcal J :=\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N\}$ such that $S_\infty:=\{f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \text{ bijection}\}$ is a $G_\delta$ set.

I tried to define the basis of the topology as something like $$A_{m,n_1,n_2}:=\{f \in \mathcal J:\{f(0),f(1),\cdots,f(m)\}\supseteq \{n_1,n_1+1,\cdots,n_2\} \text{ and } f(0),f(1),\cdots,f(m) \ \text{are different}\}.$$ Then it seems ok, since $S_\infty=\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty A_{m,0,n}. $
My questions are: (1) Is my construction right? (2) Is such a topology unique?

Edit: Sorry I got something wrong before. I have now proved (1) that this construction is right.  And I am asking for (2) because the next question is:

Let $(a_n)$ be a series that is convergent but not absolutely convergent. Prove that
$$M = \{\sigma \in S_\infty : (a_{\sigma(n)})\text{ converges}\}$$
is a set of first category in $S_\infty$.

I am trying to solve this question. So I am thinking whether the topology will influence the proof of this question.

The discrete topology seems to work. Is there some condition on the topology that you left out?


Where is your doubt?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.  2) No. Discrete topology.


Why not just define
$$B_{m,n}:={f \in \mathcal J:{f(0),f(1),\cdots,f(m)}\supseteq {0,1,\cdots,n} \text{ and } f(0),f(1),\cdots,f(m) \ \text{are different}}$$and write $S_\infty=\bigcap_{n\ge0}\bigcup_{m\ge n}B_{m,n}?$

Because I think if so,  $f \in \mathcal J, f(n)=n+1$ will not belong to any $B_{m,n}$.

I'm too lazy to decipher your topology. However, the space $\mathcal J=\prod_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathbb N$ is usually topologized as the Tychonoff product of countably namy countable discrete spaces; $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ with this topology is called the Baire space; it is a metrizable space homeomorphic to the irrational numbers. In this topology the set of injections is a closed set, and the set of all surjections is a $G_\delta$ set, as is the set of all bijections.

$f(n)=n+1$ is not onto, and my suggestion is only a simplification of notation, without changing the content.

The "next question" of your edit makes no sense as long as no topology on $S_\infty$ is specified. And a simpler topology on $\mathcal I$ for which $S_\infty$ is a $G_\delta$ is $${\varnothing,S_\infty,\mathcal I}.$$

Can you explain in detail? Why in this topology the set of injections is a closed set, and the set of all surjections is a $G_\delta$ set, as is the set of all bijections. @user14111

For one thing, the set of all surjections is $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb N}{f:f(m)=n}$$ and ${f:f(m)=n}$ is open. It is even easier to show that the set of all non-injective maps is open, whence the set of injections is a closed set and therefore (since the space is metrizable) a $G_\delta$ set. Finally the set of bijections is the intersection of the two aforementioned $G_\delta$ sets and therefore a $G_\delta$ set.

The set ${f:f(m)=n}$ is open because the projection map $f\mapsto f(m)$ is continuous, and because the set ${n}$ is open in the discrete topology of $\mathbb N$. The space $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ is metrizable because it is a countable product of metrizable spaces.
